# How can I use templates or typedefs to select between float/double vector types?

Tags: cuda

A usual way to target different floating point precisions (float / double) is either by typedefs

```
typedef float Real;
//typedef double Real;
```

or by using templates

```
template<typename Real>
...
```

This is convenient, but anyone has ideas how to use the CUDA types float2/float3/... and make_float2/make_float3/... ? Sure, I could make #defines or typedefs for all of them but that seems not very elegant.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to ask. `typedef float2 Complex;` works.

Comment: `float2` and `float3` quantities don't affect floating point precision.  They are vector types.  I suggest you clarify your question.

Comment: Exactly, if you also like to enhance precision you could use `double2`, for example, instead of `float2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement helper class that will concatenate type and channels number:

```
template <typename T, int cn> struct MakeVec;
template <> struct MakeVec<float, 3>
{
    typedef float3 type;
};
template <> struct MakeVec<double, 3>
{
    typedef double3 type;
};
// and so on for all combination of T and cn
```

Usage:

```
template <typename T>
void func()
{
    typedef typename MakeVec<T, 4>::type vec4_type;
    vec4_type vec4; // for T=float it will be float4, for T=double it will be double4
}
```

You can find implementation [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/util/vec_traits.hpp)